# Way to limit number of ports a single user can bind to concurrently

Tags: linux, networking, ip, port

On Linux, is there a way to limit the maximum number of simultaneous ports a *single user* can bind/listen to (possible on a per network device basis) at the same time?

I.e. if users can bind/listen to unlimited number of ports at the same time, a malicious user could try to tamper with port availability to other users by listening on all available ports until port exhaustion kicks in and no other user could listen to any port.

Comment: Not an answer, but may give some ideas: I used nftables, to restrict which loopback addresses a user can **connect** to. User 1 has `127.0.1.1`, user 2 has `127.0.1.2`. It does not limit listening. But may be there is some thing to allow listening restrictions on IP-address.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to listen to a port, you need to create a socket. This is done via

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

(in C). Then you can listen to that file descriptor.

A user has a maximum number of open files, see `ulimit -h` on your system for that maximum.

I do not remember exactly whether you require an actual connection for the ulimit of open files or whether a listen on a socket also counts as open file. I thought a listen also counts.

Note that a normal user is not able do bind to a port below 1024.

Selinux and apparmor also should allow control over what a user can bind as port (never tried it; just from docs).

Note that in real life, I've only seen port exhaustion for ephemeral ports, never for server ports.

Comment: I knew all of what you wrote and sadly nothing answers the question. The question is not about restricting files, or max. number of open sockets (which would also account for outgoing connections), and not about restricting the port range to bind to. Its about restricting the *maximum number of simultaneously bound ports *.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the reference to apparmor ans selinux?

Comment: I didn't miss that. It is just that "it might be in the docs somewhere" does not qualify as an answer on StackExchange. Nevertheless, I intend no disrespect and am thankful for your pointers. I will go have look there and might come back to expand the answer.